# How to deploy Crystal Reports .Net based project with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I created a `.Net` Application Which is based on Crystal Reports to display reports I want to deploy it to the client machine,please tell me the solution to successfully deploy it an order to work on client computer, I search throughout the internet but not found any clear answer to deploy `.Net` Application along with Crystal Reports.

Comment: You say you searched, but did you really? Entering your *exact* question title in Google gives you the answer as the very first result... `By` the `way`, please `don't` mark `random` words `as` if `they` are `code`, as `it` makes `it` hard `to` read `your` question.

Comment: @hvd I followed many tutorials about deployment crystal report ,but non of them really helped.
Do you have a way to deploy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i successfully deploy my `.Net` Project along with CrystalReports by using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 Merge Modules (MSM) to create my Setup project.

---

**1**. In VS .NET, open your Windows application and go to the View menu and
select Solution Explorer. Right-click your Windows application solution
and from the pop up menu, select Add then click New Project.

---

**2**. The Add New Project dialog box appears. Select Setup and Deployment
Projects in the left pane and select Setup Project in the right pane. Click
OK.

---

**3**. In the Solution Explorer, right-click the Windows application and select
Add then click Project Output…

---

**4**. The Add Project Output Group dialog box appears. Select Primary
Output to be added to your Setup project.
When the Primary Output is added to the project, some detected
dependencies will be added.
• If you are using the bundled version of CR 9, add:
managed.msm
• If you are using the full version of CR 9, exclude:
`dotnetfxredist_x86_enu.msm` and `dotnetcrystalreports.msm`
In both cases, the dotnetfxredist_x86_enu.msm and
`dotnetfxredist_x86_enu.msm` dependencies should be excluded if it is not
already.